# Using positional parametrs in bash functions

Tags: bash

Here is example, in which `$1` does not work.

```
$ cat ~/myScript
#!/bin/bash
function hello () {
echo "Hello $1"
}
hello
$ ./myScript
 Hello
```

Comment: You're not passing the parameter to the function.  Change `hello` at the bottom to `hello $1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of functions like mini-scripts within a script.  **They are ignored by the script until called upon.** So, positional parameters are ignored until passed to the function.

They are limited though as to what they can do.  I know that they cannot support `if then` statements within the function as they are ignored.  And there are some other rules, but you can `exit` your script from within a function.  If you have checking for errors with parameters those should be performed before the function is called.

You are wanting to pass positional parameters ($1, $2, $3 etc...) into your script.  However, you are expecting the positional parameter to be passed to the function.  Without specifying the parameter when you call the function, the function is not receiving the parameter.  You need to give it the parameter.

Take your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
function hello () {
echo "Hello $1"
}
hello
```

Simply by adding a `$1` to the line that just says `hello` by itself will make it so that the parameter is passed to the function.

```
#!/bin/bash
function hello () {
echo "Hello $1"
}
hello $1
```

Now calling the script with a parameter will produce the desired output:

```
$ ./myscript Terrance
Hello Terrance
```

If you want to add a quick check to it so that it doesn't take blank input after the script, add the following check into your script before the call:

```
#!/bin/bash
function hello () {
    echo "Hello $1"
}
if [[ $1 != "" ]]; then
    hello $1
    exit
else
    echo "Please input a name.  Example: $0 Terrance"
fi
```

My example script above does a check of `!=` which means `not equal to` then the two `""` means blank.  So, `if parameter 1 is not equal to blank then` is true then it runs the function call with the parameter then exits the script after the function is called.  Else it gives my error message.  The positional parameter of `$0` is the parameter of the command you just called.

Examples of my script being called:

```
$ ./myscript 
Please input a name.  Example: ./myscript Terrance


$ ./myscript Terrance
Hello Terrance
```

As you keep scripting you start to learn more tricks and proper commands and how they are used.  Keep on scripting!!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It works, but maybe you do not use it like you should. $1 refers to the first parameter of the function.

```
function hello () { echo "Hello $1" }
```

declares a function so that when you call it with parameters, it prints "Hello" and the first parameter:

```
hello WORLDDD
```

prints "Hello WORLDDD"

Comment: Tnx. By the way, how to add this fancy lines with code here. By me everything goes like one body of the text, althogh I divide it line after line..;

Comment: ctrl + K
or simply click on the button that looks like this: 
`{}`
or (it seems in the comments all of this doesn't work) by using the character ` (backquotes)